# rake aborted! invalid byte sequence in UTF-8, Rails 3, ruby 1.9.3, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, updated recently

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, rake, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

Here is the stack trace,

```
$ bundle exec rake --trace 
rake aborted!
invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:183:in `glob'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:183:in `block in have_rakefile'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:181:in `each'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:181:in `have_rakefile'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:468:in `find_rakefile_location'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:486:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/gautam/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

Anyone got a clue why this is happening? I updated my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS some days back and this started happening.

So far I have tried reinstall rvm and gemsets, reinstalling Postgresql and installed node.js locally so that execjs finds it.

Comment: The line that's blowing up is calling `Dir.glob`. Does the path to your current directory contain any non-UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Thanks @Brandan, I had worked on some ImageMagic processing before, because of which a file was created in the project folder, which had some weird encoding. This was not being tracked by Rubymine. Thanks for your comment. :) cheers.